# Cannot break from loop with ajax call in it

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using simple ajax call and depending of result of that call I want to break from a loop. It looks something like this:

```
while(true){        

   jQuery.get(url)

       .then(function(result){
            if(result === something){
                break;
            }

        });             
}
```

This just produces infinite loop. How can I achive this in other way, since this don't work?

Also I noticed that modifying any "external" variable inside `.then()` doesn't actually modify that variable, which I tried to use to break from the loop.

Some explanation of why this happens will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your get request wrapped in a while loop at all? Wrapping it in a while loop will cause you to initiate a lot of HTTP requests, if you're not going to break the loop before you get your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, the reason is that `jQuery.get()` is *asynchronous*: The function does not wait for the GET request to be finished, but returns immediately. Because of this, your code is just issuing GET requests indefinitely. The callback function in "then" is independent of this. You see the same phenomenon without a loop:

```
jQuery.get(url1).then(function () { /* A */ });
jQuery.get(url2).then(function () { /* B */ });
```

The second request is sent immediately after the first request, without waiting for code A to have executed. Both A and B are executed only once the respective requests are finished, and so B may in fact be executed prior to A.

One way to fix this is shown in Eddie's answer. Another way would be to use `Promise`s and the `async`/`await` syntax, which is supported by jQuery:

```
// "await" may appear only within async functions, so here I wrap the code
// into an immediately invoked function for demonstration
(async function () {
    while (true) {
        // "await" is key. It makes sure that the subsequent code is executed
        // only once the request is done.
        const result = await jQuery.get(url);

        if (result === something) {
            break;
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is put the `jQuery.get` on a function. Call the function again if the result NOT equals to the `something` variable

```js
function doFunction() {
  jQuery.get(url)
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result !== something) {
        doFunction(); //If result is NOT something, execute the function again
      }
    });
}

doFunction(); //Inital execute the function
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently not doing anything to negate the `while(true)`, hence the infinite loop.

The `break` in your function will only break out of that function that you're passing to the `then` callback.